# Why can't I append a string object to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and was just creating a program that manages student records like a database but for some reason I am not able to append a string object into a dictionary data structure. Any reason why?

```
def main():

# Create an empty dictionary

database = {'FIRST_NAME':'Default', 'LAST_NAME':'Default', 'ID_NUMBER':'Default'}

# Create a menu

print('\t\t\t Student Database program')
print('K: Enter student information')
print('D: Display student information')

option = input('Enter an option')

# Create a decision structure

if option == 'k' or option == 'K':
    # ask the user to enter in a student first name + last name + id number
    firstName = input('enter the students first name: ')
    lastName = input('enter the students last name: ')
    idNumber = int(input('enter the students ID number: '))

    # append these into the empty database
    database['FIRST_NAME'].append(firstName) // The error is most likelyhere
    database['LAST_NAME'].append(lastName) // The error is most likelyhere
    database['ID_NUMBER'].append(idNumber) // The error is most likely here

    print('Success!')

elif option == 'D' or option == 'd':
    # print out the values of each key
    print('Here are the students information')               
    print('')
    print(database['FIRST_NAME'])
    print(database['LAST_NAME'])
    print(database['ID_NUMBER'])

main()
```

Comment: Originally the default data are strings, Make them empty lists something like `database = {'FIRST_NAME':[], 'LAST_NAME':[], 'ID_NUMBER':[]}` (That's the most basic mistake that can be seen here, at least to my eyes)

Comment: You can't append things to strings.

Comment: Thanks. I will check and make sure that this works.

Comment: Seems like the program is working now. The only thing is my display is not working. Is there something I did wrong? All its just showing is 3 brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "append" to a dictionary, you can update or add by using its key:value.

update:

```
dict_name.update({'item1': 1})
```

add:

```
dict_name['item3'] = 3
```

Comment: @plee: If this answer has helped you, show your appreciation by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. If it is the most helpful answer, show that by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than stating your thanks in a comment.